# How to remove a route in the groovy code without using a agent in unetstack?

Tags: unetstack

As with unetstack shell we can delete a route but how to delete a route in the groovy code without using the Agent

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation for [Routing service](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_routing_and_route_maintenance.html) in the Unet handbook for how to do this. Essentially you need to send a [`EditRouteReq`](https://unetstack.net/javadoc/3.3/org/arl/unet/net/EditRouteReq.html) created using the `deleteRoute()` constructor method, and send it to the agent providing the `ROUTING` service.

For example, if you want to delete all routes to node 10, this will look something like:

```java
def router = agentForService(Services.ROUTING)
def req = EditRouteReq.deleteRoute()
req.to = 10
def rsp = router << req
// rsp will have performative AGREE if the request was successful
```